# Post parameter for redirection in Zend with Ajax/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, parameter-passing

Ok, so here's the situation: I'm using Ajax on Zend so that when I choose a date from the calendar, it redirects me to a controller (the same actually, so it's kinda a page reload) with POST parameter, so that I can show the view with the new date.

The problem is : When I select a new date, it works, redirects me to the controller, and the view page reloads but without parameters.

Here's my index.phtml:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    function update() {
        var ndate = document.getElementById("new_date").value;
        alert(ndate);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/model/control/index',
            data: ndate,
            dataType : 'html',
            success: function( data ) {
                alert('OK');
                window.location.replace('/model/control/index');                  
            }
        });
    }
}        
</script>
```

And in my ControlController.php :

```
public function relancecabAction ()
{
       if($this->getRequest()->isPost() )
            echo 'OK';
        else
            echo 'KO';
    }
```

So I get the first alert with the ndate value (date).
I get the second alert (OK) which means it's a success.
The page reloads but I still get a 'KO'.
So I still don't get the "ndate" value in the controller.

My question: How can I reload the page/redirect to a controller with a POST parameter?
How to pass the "ndate" value that I show in an alert as a POST param?
Thanks in advance, help me please.

**EDIT**

Here's a var_dump of $this->getRequest()->getParams() and getPost() using "window.location.replace('relancecab');"

```
array(3) { ["module"]=> string(7) "model" ["controller"]=> string(3) "control" ["action"]=> string(10) "index" } 
array(0) { } KO
```

and now with "window.location.replace('relancecab?ndate='+ndate);"

```
array(4) { ["module"]=> string(7) "model" ["controller"]=> string(3) "control" ["action"]=> string(10) "index" ["ndate"]=> string(10) "25/03/2014" } 
array(0) { } KO
```

As you can see the GET works but not with POST!

Comment: are you sure of your request, try to print `$this->getRequest()->getMethod()` or even the `$this->getRequest()` and see what you have.

Comment: Just edited the 1st post to answer your question. The GET works but not the POST. Thanks in advance...

Comment: because when you do `window.location.replace('/model/control/index')` you dont do a `POST` request!! i dont understand what you trying to achieve, why do you need a ajax call and a redirection?

Comment: in the success of your ajax request replace `alert('OK');` by `alert('ajax result:' + data);` and see what's in your console.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to pass a Javascript parameter as POST to the same page to change the date, so the page reloads with the new date. With alert('ajax result:' + data); it returns me an HTML page (the page I'm trying to reload). I want it to work just like in GET (which is working), but without seeing the parameters in the URL.

Comment: I think the real question is: How to reload the page AND pass a POST parameter? So that when the page loads, the POST parameter is already there. It's so easy with GET since it the controller finds it on the URL, but what about POST?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/model/control/index',
    data: "ndate=" + ndate,
    dataType : 'html',
    success: function( data ) {
        alert('OK');
        window.location.replace('/model/control/index?ndate=' + ndate);                  
    }
});
```

And handle it on controller side by getting parameters from url

**Edit:**

Also you can assign posted variable to view like;

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost() ) {
    echo 'OK';
     $ndate = $this->getRequest()->getPost('ndate', null);
     $this->view->ndate = $ndate;  
} else {
    echo 'KO';  
}
```

and you can use new date in reloaded view

Comment: and so why doing a POST request ? and not a GET

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code, it works fine, but is there any way I can use POST for the parameter? It's just that I'm asked to use POST.

Comment: In POST requests, parameters cannot be seen in url, but you can update your url to this `'/model/control/index?ndate=' + ndate` in your ajax

Comment: I don't want parameters to be seen in url. Your code works great for GET parameters, do you know how to do for POST please? Because even if I use type: 'POST' in ajax, I still can't receive any POST parameter in the controller and still get 'KO'...

Comment: do you want to post in success callback?

Comment: @user3415419 see my updated answer. You can assign posted params to view and use new ndate in reloaded view

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for POST, I'm still getting KO.

Comment: Do no use ajax just use normal for post and use my new controller code

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe generate a `form` an submit it:

```
var url = '/model/control/index';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: "ndate=" + ndate,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
        var form = $('<form></form>').attr('method', 'POST').attr('method', url);
        $.each( data , function( key, value ) {
            var input = $('<input></input>');
            input.attr('type', 'hidden');   
            input.attr('name', key);
            input.attr('value', value);
            form.append(input);
        });
        $(document.body).append(form);
        form.submit();                
    }
});
```

You will have to `json_encode` the PHP return.